# How to use linq instead of foreach loop in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find solution for the next situation:

1. I have array with Item ids

   ```
   var arrayIds = new long []{1076,2840,4839,3920,..., N};
   ```
2. I have method which returns one Item

   ```
   public Item getItem(long id) {
       return new Item{Id = id, Name = "name"};
   }
   ```
3. Here trying to get all Items

   ```
   var itemList = new List<Item>();

   foreach(var id in arrayIds) {
       itemList.Add(getItem(id));
   }
   ```

**Is it possible to use Linq here instead of `foreach`?**

I've tried to write something like that

```
itemList = arrayIds.ForEach(x => getItem(x));
```

so I have the next error here:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'action' of '`Array.ForEach<T>(T[], Action<T>)`'

So I don't know how to use Linq correctly.

Comment: [`ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach) is not a LINQ method, it's a [`List<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) method.  The methods usually referred to by "LINQ" are the extension methods defined by the [`Enumerable` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable) in the [`System.Linq` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've tried to write something like that 
>   `itemList = arrayIds.ForEach(x => getItem(x));`

`ForEach()` works on [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.8):

```
arrayIds.ToList().ForEach(x => getItem(x));
```

But what you want is:

```
var itemList = arrayIds.Select(getItem).ToList();
```

Or if you only want to enumerate the items:

```
var items = arrayIds.Select(getItem);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Select

```
var itemList = arrayIds.Select(x => getItem(x))
```